# Proof of Strassen's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am struggling to understand some parts of the proof of Strassen's theorem in Klenke's textbook.

**Theorem**. Let
$$
L = \{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x_1\le x_2\}.
$$
Then, a probability measure $\mu_2$ is stochastically larger than $\mu_1$ if and only if there is a coupling $\varphi$ of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ with $\varphi(L)=1$.

The text defines that $\mu_2$ is stochastically larger than $\mu_1$ if $\int f d\mu_1 \le \int f d\mu_2$ for every monotone increasing bounded function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Here is his proof.

> Proof. (If) Let $\varphi$ be such a coupling. For monotone increasing bounded $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have $f(x_1)-f(x_2)\le 0$ for every $x=(x_1,x_2)\in L$; hence $$ \int f d\mu_1 - \int f d\mu_2 = \int_L(f(x_1)-f(x_2))\varphi(dx)\le 0.$$
> (Only if) Here $F((x_1,x_2)):=\min(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2))$ defines a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that corresponds to a coupling $\varphi$ with $\varphi(L)=1$.

My questions:

1. Why is $\int f d\mu_1 - \int f d\mu_2=\int_L(f(x_1)-f(x_2))\varphi(dx)$? I'm not sure how to prove this because the set $L$ depends both on $x_1$ and $x_2$. If the integral is over $\mathbb{R}^2$, then I understand that from the definition of coupling, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x_1) \varphi(dx)=\int f d\mu_1$.
2. Why is $F$ a distribution function that corresponds to $\varphi$?
   I can see that the marginal of $\phi$ is indeed $\mu_i$ from $\lim_{x_j\to\infty}F(x_1,x_2)=F_i(x_i)$. However, I am not sure how to prove $\varphi(L)=1$, since $L$ is not of the "half-open box" form. I tried to think graphically and reached a wrong conclusion: take $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ such that $y_1=y_2\le x_1=x_2$. Since $F(x)=F_2(x_2)$ for $x$ on the 45 degree line, the area of $[y_1,x_1]\times [y_2,x_2]$ is $F_2(x_2)-F_2(y_2)$. Since half of the box is in $L$, by taking $x_2\to\infty$ and $y_2\to-\infty$, $\varphi(L)=(1-0)/2$?

Comment: For the first question use $\varphi(L)=1$ so that the integrals over $\mathbb R^2$ and $L$ coincide. Klenke is extremely brief in this part (example 18.7) and there are certainly quite some arguments missing. It seems that your reasoning uses that the probability of a box is $F(NE)-F(SW)$ where $NE$ and $SW$ are the *north-east* and *south-west* corners. This is not true. It is $F(NE)+F(SW)-F(SE)-F(NW)$.

Comment: I see about the first question. Regarding the second question, I see my mistake, but I realized that thinking about the area of the box is not helpful, because it only shows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x_1,x_2)=\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)=1$. Is it possible to express $L$ or $L^c$ such that I can compute the probability with $F$?

Comment: It would be enough to show that every box contained in $\mathbb R^2\setminus L$ has probability $0$. As I said, the arguments in Klenke are far too short. In the list of corrections to his book he mentions something about this example (I can't check exactly right now). You shold consult the literature he is refering to.

Comment: My previous remark concerns the first English edition from 2008, meanwhile there is a third edition. Maybe, the exmaple is better treated there.

Comment: I checked the first edition. The example you mentioned is basically relabeled verbatim as Theorem in 3rd edition. I will check "Comparison methods for stochastic models and risks."

Comment: I think the box argument works after all, although it's somewhat casual. I want to show $F(X_1\ge x, X_2\le x)=0$ for all $x$. Consider a box $(x,x),(y_1,x),(y_1,y_2),(x,y_2)$, where $y_1>x$ and $y_2<x$. The probability over the box with limit $y_1\to\infty and y_2\to -\infty$ is $F(X_1\ge x, X_2\le x)$. The probability over the box is $F(y_1,x)-F(x,x)-F(y_1,y_2)+F(x,y_2)$, which does converge to $0$ for all $x$.